# Is it possible to create jBehave story without extending JUnitStory

Tags: jbehave

I am trying to integrate jBehave into our project. Due to legacy reasons this project has some rather complex hierarchy of abstract/base test classes which contain lots of code I need to use in my jBehave stories.

Therefore, I am looking for ways to run jBehave stories without having to extend JUnitStory or JUnitStories - instead, I'd be extending our own base classes.

Is there a way to hook in jBehave into a regular jUnit test, without extending JUnitStory(es)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the very simple method can be extracted from `JUnitStories`:

```java
Embedder embedder = ...; // prepare Embedder
List<String> storyPaths = ...; // create a list of story paths to execute

try {
  embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(storyPaths);
} finally {
  embedder.generateSurefireReport(); // optional, only if Surefire report is needed
}
```